# Deleting lines matching a string in a file

Tags: bash, grep, vi, substitution

I have multiple lines in a file. some lines start in the pattern below

```
0 8234 <Enter_newLine>
0 12 <Enter_newLine>
1 2  <Enter_newLine>
```

I wanted to delete the lines which start with 0 as shown above. Can someone please help me in this

Comment: Do you like to keep or remove line like this `0.123 8234 <Enter_newLine>`

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple to do in awk:

```
awk '!/^0/' file
```

Any line starting with a 0 will not be printed.

To overwrite the input file, you can use the standard trick:

```
awk '!/^0/' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

You could also use grep:

```
grep -v '^0' file
```

The `-v` switch means that only lines that don't match the pattern are printed.

Comment: Tom, It is throwing an error when I execute this. It shows up the definition of awk

Comment: Works for me, as does the grep version. Did you copy it exactly? What version of awk are you using (not that I think it should matter)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *edit* the file, you can use `ed`, the standard editor:

```
ed -s file < <(printf '%s\n' g/^0/d w q)
```

This uses the `g/re/d` construct: `g` to use the whole file, `/re/` is the regex to work with, here `^0` to match lines starting with `0` and `d` to delete those lines. We then send the commands `w` (write) and `q` (quit).

The same without bashisms:

```
printf '%s\n' g/^0/d w q | ed -s file
```

Comment: It's not often we are treated to an answer using `ed` - +1!

Comment: You could go further with the bashishms: `ed -s file <<<$'g/^0/d\nw'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^0[[:blank:]]\+/d' file.txt
```

Assuming that there can be one or more space or tab after initial `0`, no other character.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '$1!="0"' file
1 2  <Enter_newLine>
```

This removes line where first field is just `0`.

Comment: Or just `awk '$1' file` :-)